# See status of a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I am using SharePoint Online, I am having a tough time figuring out this one. I know what I am looking for would exist but could not find where.

So I have a workflow 'approval1'. I want to know the items under this workflow and their current statuses.

```
Approve1:

File name1: Approved

File name2: Not approved

File name3: Approved
```

Could you please let me know where to go for this?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? you want to find out one which items? or lists? your workflow 'approva1' is running? and what is the status?

Comment: For the workflow 'Approve1', I want to find which files have which statuses:

eg:

File Name1: Approved
File Name2: Not Approved

etc. Thanks (I've also modified the question with a mini table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the view of your list/library and display the workflow column 'approval1'. This column will display the status of the wokflow, for example if the workflow is still running or completed. To see the approval status you will need to display the status column through modify view option.